# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, input

I am wondering why I have this error when I run this code:

```
# Ask user input
# Find out network device id for network device with ip or hostname, index 3 is device id
# In the loop until 'id' is assigned or user select 'exit'
id = ""
device_id_idx = 3
while True:
    user_input = input('=> Select a number for the device from above to show IOS config:')
    user_input= user_input.replace(" ","") # ignore space
    if user_input.lower() == 'exit': 
        sys.exit()
    if user_input.isdigit():
        if int(user_input) in range(1,len(device_show_list)+1):
            id = device_list[int(user_input)-1][device_id_idx]
            break
        else:
            print ("Oops! number is out of range, please try again or enter 'exit'")
    else:
        print ("Oops! input is not a digit, please try again or enter 'exit'")
# End of while loop
```

output error:

```
user_input= user_input.replace(" ","") # ignore space
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

This code is supposed to accept an input and return information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're using Python 2.x, where `input()` evaluates what the user types as a Python expression. Since the user has typed an integer, you get an `int` rather than a `str`. Use `raw_input()` instead and you'll always get a string.

Comment: I would encourage you to post a full code with import statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Python3.x `input` will return a string,you can try to debug your code to check the type of `user_input` or

```
print(type(user_input))
```

If you're using Python2.x `input` maybe is not a good way for your code
because `input` function evaluates your input.If your input is `1 2` you will get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`,and if your input is `1`,and it will get `int` object,this is why you got the error.

I suggest `raw_input` because `raw_input` takes exactly what the user typed and passes it back as a string.

You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)

Hope this helps.