# Python 2 to 3 migration: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

We are having two python apps with same database, one is running on python 2 and the other on python 3.
We are accessing python 2 app models in python 3 app. While all other models work fine. One model is throwing error when queried :

> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/home/pulkit/.local/share/virtualenvs/morpheus-NvWJB9pm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     41.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/home/pulkit/.local/share/virtualenvs/morpheus-NvWJB9pm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/home/pulkit/.local/share/virtualenvs/morpheus-NvWJB9pm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py" in inner
>     52.                 return func(*args, **kwds)
>
> File
>   "/home/pulkit/.local/share/virtualenvs/morpheus-NvWJB9pm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
>     551.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/pulkit/.local/share/virtualenvs/morpheus-NvWJB9pm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py"
>   in _wrapped_view
>     149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/pulkit/.local/share/virtualenvs/morpheus-NvWJB9pm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py"
>   in _wrapped_view_func
>     57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/pulkit/.local/share/virtualenvs/morpheus-NvWJB9pm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py"
>   in inner
>     224.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/pulkit/.local/share/virtualenvs/morpheus-NvWJB9pm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py"
>   in _wrapper
>     67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/pulkit/.local/share/virtualenvs/morpheus-NvWJB9pm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py"
>   in _wrapped_view
>     149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/pulkit/.local/share/virtualenvs/morpheus-NvWJB9pm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py"
>   in bound_func
>     63.                 return func.**get**(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
>
> File
>   "/home/pulkit/.local/share/virtualenvs/morpheus-NvWJB9pm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
>     1662.             selection_note=_('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
>
> File
>   "/home/pulkit/.local/share/virtualenvs/morpheus-NvWJB9pm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py"
>   in **len**
>     232.         self._fetch_all()
>
> File
>   "/home/pulkit/.local/share/virtualenvs/morpheus-NvWJB9pm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py"
>   in _fetch_all
>     1118.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
>
> File
>   "/home/pulkit/.local/share/virtualenvs/morpheus-NvWJB9pm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py"
>   in **iter**
>     62.         for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
>
> File
>   "/home/pulkit/.local/share/virtualenvs/morpheus-NvWJB9pm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py"
>   in results_iter
>     847.                     row = self.apply_converters(row, converters)
>
> File
>   "/home/pulkit/.local/share/virtualenvs/morpheus-NvWJB9pm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py"
>   in apply_converters
>     832.                 value = converter(value, expression, self.connection, self.query.context)
>
> File
>   "/home/pulkit/.local/share/virtualenvs/morpheus-NvWJB9pm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/operations.py"
>   in convert_uuidfield_value
>     244.             value = uuid.UUID(value)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/uuid.py" in **init**
>     137.             hex = hex.replace('urn:', '').replace('uuid:', '')
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/orders/gmasorder/ Exception
>   Value: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: How is hex being set? The error is saying it's an int, and the int type has no replace() method. Looking at the syntax that looks like a str.replace() call.

I suspect something that sets hex returns an int where you expected it to return a string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41390420/4758119

Comment: Seems  like the value you have in hex is `int`. You might need to convert it to string first

Comment: Thanks DeepakMahakale and codingatty but I am not sure from where this function is being called. I have defined  __str__ function under model which returns string but no idea what is invoking convert_uuidfield_value function.

Comment: Can you show your model that is throwing this exception?